# pdflatex doesn't install packages on the fly

Tags: pdftex, packages, initex

I'm trying to write a script to set up `TeXworks` (`MiKTeX`) so that upon calling `pdflatex` ... from the command window it would install the missing packages on the called .tex document.

The script is run in Matlab and in pseudocode, this is what it does:

- parses the .tex file to get the required package names
- checks which ones are installed (using **kpsewhich packageName.sty**)
- if at least one is missing sets property of MiKTeX to autoinstall on the fly (using **initexmf --set-config-value [MPM]AutoInstall=1**)
- generates pdf **pdflatex filename.tex**

but the on the last point, the pdflatex call, it doesn't really install packages on-the-fly and returns an error:

```
! LaTeX Error:  File 'hieroglyph.sty' not found
```

Is it possible that pdflatex doesn't support on-the-fly installation and am I just assuming it should work? I couldn't find anything in the docs.

Alternatively, since from point 4 of the pseudocode onwards I know which package is missing before compiling, I could install the package myself without it being on-the-fly, but I could not find any command to do so. Is it possible to install a package from the command line?

for reference: Windows/ MiKTeX 4.9 / TeXworks

Comment: there is no hieroglyph.sty, the name of the sty is `hieroglf`  (old packages often have file names with at most 8 chars as the older OS couldn't handle more)

Comment: This is most likely a matter of the installer. E.g. I configured my Miktex to ask for permission to install a missing package. I‘m not aware, Latex can or is intended to do that.

Comment: sorry @MS-SPO i dont understand what you mean

Comment: @FerroLuca, kindly have a look at "Automatic package installation" in https://miktex.org/howto/miktex-console .